# can byte buddy be used as debugger

Tags: java, debugging, byte-buddy

Is it possible to use byte-buddy in order to record all method calls, variables at some points in time, exceptions that happened and line numbers?

I wanted to record all this data in java app.

Comment: Yes byte-buddy can be used to write something like that. But it would be easier to use an existing tool. They are called Application Performance Monitor. E.g. Instana or dynatrace.

Comment: By digging more into details, it seems this is not possible with byte buddy - since I need to use JVMTI (only native support), or to use jdw which is basically proxifying to other java app (remote debug).

Answer (score 0):

You can of course do so by intercepting any method of your entire program. But in general, this is not recommended. JVMTI exposes "real breakpoints" that are not available in the Java API if this is what you are looking for.

If you do however want to record all calls, instrumentation would be an option but intercepting any call would probably generate too much overhead. For a tool using Byte Buddy that does selective monitoring, have a look at [Stage Monitor that is open source](https://github.com/stagemonitor/stagemonitor).